System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
While trying to connect with server using TLS1.3 facing below issue on line
**HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse(); **
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at FileDownloadManager.Utility.GetResponseFromURL(String URL)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
On server .net framework 4.8 is installed but the solution is build on .net framework 4.5
building complete solution on 4.8 is not feasible for now
any luck or any way we can try to pass this error
Thanks in Advance✌

How is tls configured for both client and server?

Are the OSes on the involved machines capable of Tls1.3? Anything below Windows 11 isn't.

On client server they have only TLS1.3 and at our side we have both TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 but later we are going to remove the TLS1.2

Both server are on windows server 2022 capable of using TLS1.3

I'd love to know whose hair-brained idea it was to disable TLS1.2, as there is nothing wrong with it. .NET4.8 doesn't support TLS1.3 on Windows 10 or Server 2019 and below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls Use Wireshark to watch the Client and Server Hello messages, so you can see the version or cipher or hash mismatch (there needs to be at least one common between client and server for each). Use the IIS Crypto tool to change the system settings.

Also HttpWebResponse is deprecated, use HttpClient instead. Do not specify ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

We dont have access of client server, we can only make changes on our server. The main thing we can not disable TLS1.2 from server other wise we are not able to take the RDP of server.
The same setting is working when I am using TLS 1.2 for connection Only issue I am facing when defining the route through TLS1.3

We have used HttpClient also
var client1 = new HttpClient();
var response1 = client1.SendAsync(request1);
var respo = response1.Result;
Getting Error at the third line as
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

I think we just told you that you need to target 4.8 on Windows 11, otherwise this is never going to work with TLS1.3. HttpClient won't fix your issue, it's just good practice anyway. Also you are using it wrong: you should use await not .Result, and you should dispose the request and response with using, but do not re-create the client on each run.

I tried also targeting the framework 4.8 by making changes in config but same issue


And which version of Windows? And what are your enabled ciphers? Did you run a Wireshark trace, what did you see? Help us to help you, we can't see your screen.

What I have done in recent time is that I have created a stub just like our client server and hosted the stub on our same server, When I am connecting to the stub with TLS1.2 its working but while connecting using TLS1.3 same issue is replicating

Enabled Cipher - AES 256/256
Windows - Windows Server 2022

Code line used for TLS1.2 - ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;  and for TLS1.3 - ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288;

I have build my application with .Net Framework 4.8.1 and change the line code to ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
Still facing the same issue

Cipher suite enable at Client site(Linux) is TLS1.2/1.3, AES 256, SHA 256/384, ECDH and Server Site (windows) is TLS1.2/1.3, AES 256, SHA 256/384/512, Diffie-Hellman/PKCS/ECDH
